# Correct bad data in database latest-flag

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, join

```
Background
```

My database is keeping track of users and their changing user names. Each real person can have had many user names over time, but only one is the "Latest" (the current one). This is achieved by having a from-date and to-date, where if it it the latest one, toDate is null and have latest-column set to 1. Unfortunately, the data has been corrupted and now some users don't have a latest-flag. 
And another bug is that some have toDate that is null even though it shouldn't be.

```
Question
```

How can I find the rows that needs to set/update the latest-flag to 1 ? (No need to worry about second bug for now, but it might make it trickier to find the right row to update latest flag).

The correct SELECT should return row 5 and 8 (but not row 6), in the example below.

```
Example
```

PersonId=1 is a correct person.
PersonId=2 is missing the latest=1 in row 5.
PersonId=3 has the second bug (toDate=null) in row 6 and is missing latest=1 in row 8.

To avoid the second bug (row 5), we know that the fromDate is always bigger(newer) for the row that needs to be corrected.

I've tried to make a join but I couldn't get it right...

Here is the table "users":

```
+----+--------+----------+------------+------------+--------+
| id | name   | personId | fromDate   | toDate     | latest |
+----+--------+----------+------------+------------+--------+
|  1 | Perold |        1 | 2016-12-01 | 2016-12-31 |      0 |
|  2 | Pernew |        1 | 2016-12-31 | NULL       |      1 |
|  3 | Body   |        2 | 2016-01-01 | 2016-12-01 |      0 |
|  4 | Bo     |        2 | 2016-12-01 | 2016-12-31 |      0 |
|  5 | Bonew  |        2 | 2016-12-31 | NULL       |      0 | <-- Wrong latest
|  6 | Joe    |        3 | 2016-01-01 | NULL       |      0 | <-- Wrong toDate, correct latest
|  7 | Joey   |        3 | 2016-12-01 | 2016-12-31 |      0 |
|  8 | Jo     |        3 | 2016-12-31 | NULL       |      0 | <-- Wrong latest
+----+--------+----------+------------+------------+--------+
```

Comment: Is this for MySQL??

Comment: Yes, sorry. I should have written Im using MySQL 5.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself eventually. Here is the final result. I did it with a join but with help of other solutions.

```
SELECT u1.id
   FROM USERS u1
   INNER JOIN users u2 ON u2.id = u1.id AND u2.latest = 0 AND u2.todate is null
   INNER JOIN  
    (
        SELECT  personid, MAX(fromdate) max_date
        FROM    users ux
        GROUP   BY personId
    ) x ON  u2.personid = x.personid AND
            u2.fromdate = x.max_date
    WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT NULL FROM users u3 WHERE u1.PersonId = u3.PersonId AND u3.latest = 1);
```

The first inner join had to get rid of the todate that is not null. It showed up in the real data. The last "where not exists" is to get rid of the users that already are correct.

Answer (score 1):

For #1 you can find the bad rows with a sub-query that finds the maximum `fromDate` for each user. That's the only one that should have `latest` = 1.

Something like the following (I didn't test this):

```
SELECT u.id FROM users u WHERE u.latest = 0 
AND u.fromDate = (SELECT MAX(u_sorted.fromDate) FROM user u_sorted WHERE u_sorted.personId=u.personId);
```

The second part is easy once you've already fixed #1 so you can rely on the `latest` column. This time you want to find all rows EXCEPT the most recent where `toDate` is null.

```
SELECT id FROM user WHERE latest = 0 AND toDate IS NULL;
```

The only trick now is to fix these rows. You probably want to set the missing toDate to one day earlier than the fromDate of that person's next chronological entry. (Personally I'd get rid of the toDate column and replace it with an `is_active` column store on the user's profile, but that's another topic.)

Note: The above queries assume that the fromDate column wasn't corrupted, has no duplicates, and is not null.

Comment: Note: I made an assumption that if a person becomes inactive, the toDate of their most recent gets filled in but latest is still 1 in that row. If instead latest should be set to 0, a small change to my first query is needed.

Comment: I couldn't get that to work... It listed all id's except no 2... I think it is missing some 'group by' maybe? I want to find the latest date for that particular personId and not only for that row. Or maybe I dont understand the inner select...

Comment: Looks like I used id instead of personId in there. I will fix.

Comment: It's ok. I figured it out using inner joins. Please check out my answer. Thanks for helping me get there.

Comment: Your solution looks equivalent to my first query (once I'd corrected it :smile:). Yours uses group by instead of a correlated subquery. Yours might be more efficient on some databases, though I suspect a good db engine will end up with a similar execution plan either way.. Glad you were able to figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

Asserting that fromDate has always a value and that the intervals fromDate-toDate for each persnId are dense populated, here is my proposal.

First we compute the next toDate value and guess if it is the first and/or the last record for a personId with window functions.

Then, we apply some rules (CASES) to get the valid values only for those records that shows a bad value. Last, filter to obtain only this records. In the final resulset, we can see the original record values and the newToDate and newLatest record value. We will must updeta only the fields that shows a newX value (maybe one or both)

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT id,
               name, 
               personId
               fromDate, 
               toDate, 
               latest, 
               CASE WHEN isFirst = 1 AND toDate IS NULL THEN nextValue 
                    WHEN isLast = 0  AND toDate IS NULL THEN nextValue 
                    ELSE NULL END newToDate, 
               CASE WHEN isLast <> latest   
                    THEN isLast 
                    ELSE NULL END newLatest
          FROM (SELECT yourTable.*, 
                       LEAD(yourTable.fromDate) OVER (PARTITION BY yourT able.personId ORDER BY yourTable.fromDate  ASC) nextValue,
                       (CASE WHEN yourTable.fromDate = FIRST_VALUE(yourTable.fromDate)  OVER (PARTITION BY yourTable.personId ORDER BY  yourTable.fromDate  ASC)  
                             THEN 1 
                             ELSE 0 END) AS isFirst,
                       (CASE WHEN yourTable.fromDate = FIRST_VALUE (yourTable.fromDate) OVER (PARTITION BY yourTable.personId ORDER BY yourTable.fromDate  DESC) 
                             THEN 1 
                             ELSE 0 END) AS isLast
                  FROM yourTable)) 
 WHERE newToDate IS NOT NULL   
    OR newLatest IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I had trouble getting this to work. It didn't like the "LEAD(...) OVER". Not sure why. Im using MySQL 5.7, maybe thats why... Thanks for the help in any case. I hope my solution is correct but maybe I missed something.